# Calling Java method from JavaScript using ScriptEngine

Tags: java, javascript, scripting

I'm using ScriptEngine, running JavaScript.

I want the JavaScript script to be able to call myFunction(), where myFunction() is a method inside a given class of mine.

I know it's possible to use importPackage for standard Java stuff, what about my own methods?

Please advise :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jsimport), when you do

```
importPackage(java.awt)
```

in a script, that's actually a shortcut for a built-in global variable called `Packages` -- "java.awt" is actually a shortcut for "Packages.java.awt".  So you might try and see whether, if you create your own package called "com.mypackage.hello", the scripting engine can access `Packages.com.mypackage.hello`.  I haven't been able to find any documentation on that, but it's worth trying.

Comment: It worked!

I didn't know about the Packages thing, solved my problem.

Comment: @JacobM, What if the java method called in the script doesn't exist?

Comment: @Joe.wang: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Presumably if the java method doesn't exist, then you'll get an error saying the function is not defined.

Comment: @JacobM Yes, Actually, I am not sure if I can know this kind of `specified java method in script doesn't exist` error before script running . I mean in the compile time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are actually trying to do but typically, you would make an **HTTP Request** from your JavaScript using [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) to talk to backend service exposed through HTTP.

You will have to make your Java Class function accessible through a servlet/HTTP interface.

Comment: No, the poster isn't talking about javascript running in a browser, but in the Java 6 scripting engine (JSR 00023).